# What is the most efficient way to check several conditions in columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working through a pandas dataframe with three relevant columns and 2.7 million rows. The structure is:

```
key VisitLink   dx_filter   time
0   1   ddcde14 1   100
1   2   abcde11 1   140
2   3   absdf12 1   50
3   4   ddcde14 0   125
4   5   ddcde14 1   140

data = [[1,'ddcde14',1,100],[2,'abcde11',1,140],[3,'absdf12',1,50],[4,'ddcde14',0,125],[5,'ddcde14',1,140]]
df_example = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['key','VisitLink','dx_filter','time'])
```

I need 3 things to be true:
- **VisitLink**: matches between the two rows
- **dx_filter**: is 1 for the first event
- **Time**: the second event happens within 30 days of the first event
**Example:** Key 1 will generate Key 4 as a matching record, as it meets all qualifications, but Key 4 will not generate Key 5 because its dx_filter = 0.

I ran a trial where I predicted my method would take 120+ hours to complete and am wondering if there is a way to shorten this to <10 hours or if that is not possible.

```
def add_readmit_id(df):
    df['readmit_id'] = np.nan
    def set_id(row):
        if row['dx_filter'] ==0:
            return np.nan
        else:
            relevant_df = df.loc[df['VisitLink']==row['VisitLink']]
            timeframe_df = relevant_df.loc[(relevant_df['time']>row['time'])&(relevant_df['time']<=row['time']+30)]
            next_timeframe = timeframe_df['time'].min()
            id_row = timeframe_df.loc[timeframe_df['time']==next_timeframe]
            if not id_row.empty:
                return id_row.iloc[0]['key']
            else:
                return np.nan
    df['readmit_id'] = df.apply(set_id,axis=1)
    return df

df_example = add_readmit_id(df_example)
```

See above for the code I used to run it #minimum reproducible.

Comment: Can you include an actual sample of your dataframe, as well as the expected output with that sample dataframe? Simplify your problem down to a reproducible example

Comment: Honestly don't know how to paste in displayed dataframe output into these text boxes, the structure disappears.

Comment: Is it at most a `1:1` join between rows (like you'd always want to group the closest within 30 days if multiple match) or possibly a `1:m` join so that you'd join all that match within 30 days?

Comment: Copy the dataframe (raw text) into your original post and then highlight it and press CTRL-K, it will format

Comment: Possibly 1:m join between visitlinks, times will always be unique across visitlinks that match.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as it stands the data is not in a convenient format to use.

Comment: Probably going to be easiest with a merge. It's an interesting question, but you should modify your input data such that some VisitLink will match and then provide your expected output from that sample.

Comment: @katardin run `df.to_dict`, and include the output from your console as `df=pd.DataFrame(<your dictionary>)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach with `groupby`:

```
groups = df.groupby('VisitLink')
s = groups['time'].diff(-1).le(30) & df['dx_filter']
df['shifted'] = np.where(s, groups['key'].shift(-1), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   key VisitLink  dx_filter  time  shifted
0    1   ddcde14          1   100      4.0
1    2   abcde11          1   140      NaN
2    3   absdf12          1    50      NaN
3    4   ddcde14          0   125      NaN
4    5   ddcde14          1   140      NaN
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to let it run long enough to get an actual answer on the relative efficiency of this - one drawback is it doesn't let me run a counter / tracker to see how quickly it does each 100/1k/10k/100k rows.

Comment: should be pretty fast on your 2.7 million rows. No more than 10 seconds I would say. But that also depends on how many unique `VisitLink` in your data.

Comment: There are ~1.8m unique VisitLinks - the majority are unique unfortunately - let it run for 30 min locally, so I'm going to move it to a cloud cpu and will update on how long it takes!